# Can I download all transactions into EOS ICO as a excel file?

Tags: ether, external-api, explorer-api

I would like to download all transactions into EOS ICO as an excel file. I know etherscan provides this service but it only allows me to download 2000 transactions. But the transactions into EOS crowd sale address is already over 50000, so this option does not meet my need.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to download the transactions in a similar form that etherscan provides, but without the restriction of 2000. The information I need looks like the following:

DateTime/sender address(from)/ Value in / Value out/Historical price/status

I am not a computer science guy but willing to do some coding if I need. Is it any plausible solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Google just recently announced that they created a public dataset for whole ethereum blockchain [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them)  [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics)

You can sign up using your google account and can use BigQuery from google to get all kind of stuff out of ethereum blockchain. They already have some really cool graphs in the above mentioned link. [Github](https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl) link to the repo, using this you can export whole blockchain to excel sheet or just contracts or token transfers (May take more time).

You can do some [cool stuff](https://medium.com/google-cloud/analysing-1-2m-mainnet-contracts-in-20-seconds-using-eveem-and-bigquery-f69b6d66c7b2) using Googles BigQuery or something like [this](https://showme-1389.appspot.com/)

Comment: This works, but I always worry that if I use this method to find transactions on my own accounts, Google will attach my name to my address. Just warning people to be careful when searching for transactions on public websites (including EtherScan, Alethio, AmberData, etc.) They are not providing free access to this data because they're kind.

Answer (score 0):

Scan all blocks since the EOS ICO contract was deployed / crowdfunding started. And filter for transactions that call the EOS contract.
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber

Comment: This takes many, many hours and does not find token purchases that went through smart contracts (multi-sigs for example). In the case of a multi-sig, the user sends the transaction to the multi-sig, not the token contract. Searching on 'to' won't find that transaction.